# Enable Image Upload Button in ckeditor in Python/Django

Tags: javascript, python, django, ckeditor

I am using ekeditor in one of my Python/Django project . I have enable the editor with `create_editor('id_of_filed')` , [image]   but I want image upload button in this editor and I don't know how to do that. I have read docs of ckeditor but those docs are mostly for **PHP and .NET** . But I want this for Django (However this editor uses JS so language doesn't matter). I have find this code in docs

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1',
    {
        filebrowserBrowseUrl : '/browser/browse.php',
        filebrowserUploadUrl : '/uploader/upload.php'
    });
```

But in my case what are the files I have to mention here because I am not using PHP but Python/Django instead.

Answer (score 2):

I recently solved the same problem.First of all Upload tab is hidden in the image plugin dialog.You have to search for the upload tab in image.js dialog file and change the field 'hidden' to false.

Now for Django/Python you have to provide the url of the view which will handle image upload.For ex - /editor/upload.

```
config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl = '/editor/upload/';
```

in the config.js file.

In the view goes the code where you have to handle fetching file from the request and saving it in the media directory of the Django project.

You can take help from django-ckeditor.I read the full code of django-ckeditor in and out and implemented the upload functionality by using the way in which django-ckeditor was doing it.

Also one more thing, django-ckeditor does not handle csrf-protection while uploading images so you might have to probably change something on the front end side to handle POST data which you will be sending to the django backend. For that check this link -

[How to add a field to POST values in CKeditor upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392582/how-to-add-a-field-to-post-values-in-ckeditor-upload?rq=1)

First try this and let me know if you are facing any problem.

Comment: Seven years later and setting `config.filebrowserImageUploadUrl` still worked for me, to get the 'Upload' tab to appear, and work, in a CKEditor that appears in a JavaScript-generated modal window on an otherwise Django-powered site with django-ckeditor v6.4.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem as you. On the `django-ckeditor` GitHub page they write (emphasis my own):

> Provides a RichTextField, RichTextUploadingField, **CKEditorWidget** and **CKEditorUploadingWidget** utilizing CKEditor with image upload and browsing support included.

In my `forms.py` for my text I had

```
class BlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorWidget())
```

which gave me the same editor as you had. I changed it to

```
class BlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    text = forms.CharField(widget=CKEditorUploadingWidget())
```

This gave me a tab to upload an image from my computer, which was then uploaded to my `MEDIA_URL` and served as one would expect.

Answer (score 1):

By default CKEditor does not include a file browser or uploader. You can, however, [create a custom file browser](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browse_upload) or use an existing product like [CKFinder](http://cksource.com/ckfinder), and then configure CKEditor to use it thanks to its [file browser API](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_browser_api).

The code that you quote above configures CKEditor to use such custom file browser which is definded in some `browse.php` and `upload.php` files, but it's no magic - these are simply some file browser's custom scripts. In your case you can replace them with your own file upload functionality or some ready-made solution that's already available.