# How to add a csrf token to a post request in a image upload in CKEDITOR plugin?

Tags: javascript, django, ckeditor, image-uploading

I am using a enhanced image plugin to upload the image to the server.My backend is Django.By taking some help from django-ckeditor I have implemented the frontend and backend part of image upload in CKEDITOR.

However Django-Ckeditor does not handle csrf protection in image upload. It uses csrf_exempt decorator to exempt from csrf protection.

```
upload = csrf_exempt(ImageUploadView.as_view())
```

How to add csrf token to the post request which is made for image upload?Will I have to write my own form in the upload plugin which handles csrf token?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add a field to POST values in CKeditor upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10392582/how-to-add-a-field-to-post-values-in-ckeditor-upload)

Comment: You already linked to that post 2 days ago in another question

Comment: @AlfonsoML - yeah But I am not able to upload it to server and get back the URL of the image by that method.Have you tried that method? If yes then can you share with me how ?

Comment: No, I haven't tested that because I have my own plugin that takes care of all the file uploads and this is just one of the features that it provides. You should debug your code to find out why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: I can't write the full answer right now, but take a look at [`editor.fileUploadRequest`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-fileUploadRequest) and http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_upload-section-editor-side-configuration

Answer (score 3):

The easy way is to add csrf token in filebrowserImageUploadUrl, see below (jsp)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var editor = CKEDITOR.replace('content', { skin: 'moonocolor',
      toolbar: 'MyToolbar', 
      filebrowserImageUploadUrl: "<c:url value="/site/upload"/>${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}" });
   }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I've simply concatenated the csrf token to my uploading url:

```
filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '/laravel-filemanager/upload?type=Images&_token=' + $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr("content"),
```